# CSS not being applied on Angular application

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I have a Modal service which HTML/CSS is working fine ([StackBlitz Angular Static HTML](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-angular-flex-1))

```css
div.cover {

  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;

}

div.modal {

  background-color: white;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 60vh;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;

}

div.head {

  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px;

}

div.body {

  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;

}

div.view {
  padding: 20px 28px;
}

div.foot {

  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 20px;

}

p {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor aliquet orci sit amet fringilla. Duis a ligula consequat, ornare elit eu, tincidunt turpis.
</p>
<p>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor.
</p>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="head">
      <div>Head</div>
      <div><a href="#">Close</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="view">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor aliquet orci sit amet fringilla. Duis a ligula consequat, ornare elit eu, tincidunt turpis.
</p>
<p>
  Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor.
</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foot">
      Foot
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I then used a Modal.Service to open the content [StackBlitz Angular Modal Service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-angular-flex-2)

When "Open Modal" is clicked the Modal shows and it looks as expected.

However when the browser window is resized in its height the modal does not resize.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The flex is incomplete, you need to define more to get expected behavior when it hits the **max-height** parameter. For example, if you want it to shrink and scroll when the content overflows with the vh shrinking try:

```
div.modal {

  background-color: white;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 60vh;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;

  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Defining the **flex-shrink** is really the big part there though.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-angular-flex-2-rysjej

Comment: Your code does not work ... The modal is resized but its content disappears ...

Comment: And what is strange is that my code is working when not using the Modal Service (Check first StackBlitz example of my question) but does not work when using the Modal Service.

Comment: The difference is that in your first one it doesn't have a "content" DOM element inserted around the modal.

Comment: Yes, that is because I am loading the Modal's content from an Angular component. But shouldn't the CSS be applied nevertheless? I can't find anything in the CSS that would make the content tag to matter ...

Comment: The content tag removes flex layout design that the modal offers. If you don't want the modal view to be completely scrollable (as it is in my answer) you will need to dynamically style the content container to allow flex (to allow only middle content to flex shrink with overflow y).

Comment: Shouldn't :host, :host-contex or ::ng-deep be able to solve this? I have been trying and it has some effects but does not solve it completely.

Comment: What do you mean with add it dynamically?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look that deep and only saw you were adding other styles dynamic. You can definitely use the :host to apply the flex to the parent. Likely want to leave it at 100% height, 100% width, display flex, and flex-shrink 1. I have to leave, sorry I couldn't fully solve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of mistakes. And angular encompasses your HTML around the component selector element. In this case your modal content was inside `<content>` which doesn't have flex applied.

```css
div.cover {
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.modal {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div.modal > content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```